# Como alterar a fonte e cor das legendas do eixo x?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou com dificuldades em alterar o tamanho e cor da legenda do eixo x. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
salinity <- data.frame(Areas= c("São Marcos beach", "Jansen Lagoon", "Calhau beach"),
                               Salinity=c(21.2, 19.7, 2.16))

ggplot(salinity, aes(x=Areas,y=Salinity)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .55, fill = gray(.2)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,25), breaks = seq(0,25,5)) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 18) + xlab(NULL) +
  ylab("Salinity")
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar: `theme(axis.text.x = element_text())`

Como seus parâmetros de interesse são **tamanho** e **cor**, você precisa mexer em `size =`  e `color =`

Exemplo:

```
ggplot(salinity, aes(x=Areas,y=Salinity)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .55, fill = gray(.2)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,25), breaks = seq(0,25,5)) + 
  theme_classic(base_size = 18) + 
  xlab(NULL) + 
  ylab("Salinity")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, colour = "orange"))
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]